# HttpWebRequest: how to identify as a browser?

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

The question is how to construct `HttpWebRequest` so queried server will think it comes from a browser?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could set the [User-Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx) HTTP request header.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
```

or if you work with a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
    ...
}
```