# C# make POST request via internet explorer and retrieve response back in to C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, post

I am writing a C# application whereby I formulate the POST strings in C# but the website I am POSTing recognizes that I am not using IE, Chrome or Firefox. Is there a way that I can "use" Internet Explorer (or either of the other two browsers) to make the POST request and then retrieve the response back in the C# (to parse the HTML)?

I have this currently:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    //Any key-value arguments for the POST are stored in data
    var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Forge the User-Agent HTTP header. The User-Agent header basically tells the receiving server what program is sending the packets to it.

[See this StackOverflow answer on how to do just that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11841680/3375557)

Answer (score 0):

```
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
```

place after response

also

[Other Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278057/httpwebrequest-how-to-identify-as-a-browser)

Comment: Why after response? Shouldn't this need to modify the wb.UploadValus() line? :)